# Can't get the Generic Sensor API to work in a React app

Tags: reactjs, sensors

I'm trying to implement the Generic Sensor API in a React app.

https://www.w3.org/TR/generic-sensor/#the-sensor-interface

I keep getting an error when I try to implement any of the sensors in my code. 
For example:

```
  var sensor1 = new AmbientLightSensor();
```

I get the error: Cannot find name: 'AmbientLightSensor'.

I assume that I need an import statement in my code. All of the examples I've found only include LitElement. I've even tried that but still get the unknown error.

1. What import statements do I need in my typescript code?
2. What npm packages do I need?

Below is the typescript code I'm using.

I'm getting a typescript error:

> /Users/scoleman/dev/current/bigbrother/src/utility/testAccel.ts(14,24):
>   Cannot find name 'AmbientLightSensor'.  TS2304

```
  export const testAccel = async (
    databaseName: string,
  ) => {

    const {state} = await navigator.permissions.query({
        name: "ambient-light-sensor"
    });

    if (state !== "granted") {
        console.warn("You haven't granted permission to use the light sensor");
        return;
    }

    const sensor = new AmbientLightSensor();

    sensor.addEventListener("reading", () => {
        console.log(sensor.illuminance);
    });

    sensor.addEventListener("error", (err: any) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

    sensor.start();

  };
```

Comment: [What browser are you trying to do this in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AmbientLightSensor#Browser_compatibility)?

Comment: Additionally, are you doing this over HTTPS?

Comment: Please try to share all relevant code  and not just a single expression. Try to share a [Minimal, Reproducible, and Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Without this it is impossible to know what code you're trying to access, how you've initialized any external modules, or how you're trying to interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get these api's running using the polyfill at:

https://github.com/kenchris/sensor-polyfills

Answer (score -1):

This would depend entirely on the browser you are using.  I don't think FireFox supports it at the moment so I will focus on Chrome.

Firstly, you *might* need to be serving your site over [HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sensors-for-the-web#only_https).  It seems like this almost varies from permission to permission and also some are available on a localhost URL no matter what.

Secondly, for Chrome, you have to enable the "Generic Sensor Extra Classes" flag in Chrome at the `chrome://flags/#enable-generic-sensor-extra-classes` page.

[image: Chrome Flags Page]

Next, you need to make sure that have permission from the user to use the sensor, then you could actually use it.  A snippet that would check that is as follows:

```
(async function(){
    const {state} = await navigator.permissions.query({
        name: "ambient-light-sensor"
    });

    if (state !== "granted") {
        console.warn("You haven't granted permission to use the light sensor");
        return;
    }

    const sensor = new AmbientLightSensor();

    sensor.addEventListener("reading", () => {
        console.log(sensor.illuminance);
    });

    sensor.addEventListener("error", err => {
        console.error(err);
    });

    sensor.start();
}());
```

Comment: @user3786170 You should edit that into your question, not post it as a comment.